# Account Creation-Email To Google Sheets

Tags: flutter, firebase, email

I'm having an issue with flutterflow/firebase during account creation.  I need to have the users email address go to a google sheet so that I'm able to manage the account properly.  I don't get any errors from flutterflow except it doesn't show the email address text field in test mode (so that I can test in real time).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I cleared all errors and Google searched the error I was receiving.  The data is already listed as "String" so I'm not sure what the issue is.  Everything has been authenticated and is correct.

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. For example, what's the error you were receiving?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.